# How to call multiple values in .innerHTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a date stamp next to `prev` variable. I am also trying to run this function each time, but it only runs first time and after saving it's not running.

```js
var date = Date();
$(document).on('focusin', 'input', function() {
  console.log("Saving value " + $(this).val());
  $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
}).on('change', 'input', function() {
  var prev = $(this).data('val');
  var current = $(this).val();

  if (prev !== current) {
    $(this).css("color", $currentDayColor);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'The Prev Value is :' + prev + date;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 'The Current Value is :' + current + date;
  };
});
```

Comment: "after saving" means what?

Comment: I am using this in a worksheet which gets saved. it has a save button

Comment: okay and does it change the page in anyway that unbinds the events because of a redraw? I see the event delegation, just wondering if somehow it is breaking that. Did you add console.log lines to see if things are being called?

Comment: yes i used console.log it's not breaking

Comment: The change event only fires when the input loses focus, so if you change `'change'` to `'keyup'` you might get the result you desire.

Comment: You're not updating the `date` variable, it's only set when the page first loads.